# HTML onclick="myFunction" not working

Tags: javascript, html

First, i have checked several tutorial sites to clarify syntax such as the OnClick event and the prompt property and relocated the javascript from body to head (I heard this can fix browser-related problems).

For some reason OnClick event does nothing. I have tested website in-browser and radio buttons load correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function checkSkillLevel() {
        if(document.getElementById('skill_Easy').checked) {
            var ok = prompt("You chose Easy");
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('skill_Medium').checked) {
            var ok = prompt("You chose Medium");
        }
        else if document(getElementById('skill_Hard').checked) {
            var ok = prompt("You chose Hard");
        }
        else {
            var ok = prompt("Welcome to my tic tac toe game! To get started, please pick a skill level.");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
            <td><h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form action="" onclick="checkSkillLevel()">
            <input type="radio" name="skill" value="Easy" id="skill_Easy" onclick="checkSkillLevel();">Easy<br>
            <input type="radio" name="skill" value="Medium" id="skill_Medium">Medium<br>
            <input type="radio" name="skill" value="Hard" id="skill_Hard">Hard<br>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Also, I would prefer pure Javascript (no JQuery please) for any ideas.

Comment: You can't "click" a form, only submit `onsubmit` it.

Comment: And where do you click?

Comment: You only have `onclick` on the `Easy` button. You need to put it on all the buttons. And remove it from the form, as @joaumg said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `onclick` to all the inputs, and correct the typo in the following line :

```
else if document(getElementById('skill_Hard').checked) {
```

Should be :

```
else if(document.getElementById('skill_Hard').checked) {
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
function checkSkillLevel() {
  if(document.getElementById('skill_Easy').checked) {
    var ok = prompt("You chose Easy");
  }
  else if(document.getElementById('skill_Medium').checked) {
    var ok = prompt("You chose Medium");
  }
  else if(document.getElementById('skill_Hard').checked) {
    var ok = prompt("You chose Hard");
  }
  else {
    var ok = prompt("Welcome to my tic tac toe game! To get started, please pick a skill level.");
  }
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <td><h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="skill" value="Easy" id="skill_Easy" onclick="checkSkillLevel();"/>Easy<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="skill" value="Medium" id="skill_Medium" onclick="checkSkillLevel();"/>Medium<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="skill" value="Hard" id="skill_Hard" onclick="checkSkillLevel();"/>Hard<br/>
        
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick-attr or an onchange-attr with the function to each radio-button and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about which elements are listening to the `onclick` event. The form does not have `onclick`, it has `onsubmit`. The *buttons* have `onclick`, though.

```
<td>
    <form action="" onclick="checkSkillLevel()">
    <input type="radio" name="skill" value="Easy" id="skill_Easy" onclick="checkSkillLevel();">Easy<br>
    <input type="radio" name="skill" value="Medium" id="skill_Medium">Medium<br>
    <input type="radio" name="skill" value="Hard" id="skill_Hard">Hard<br>
</td>
```

Becomes:

```
<td>
    <form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="skill" value="Easy" id="skill_Easy" onclick="checkSkillLevel();">Easy<br>
    <input type="radio" name="skill" value="Medium" id="skill_Medium" onclick="checkSkillLevel();">Medium<br>
    <input type="radio" name="skill" value="Hard" id="skill_Hard" onclick="checkSkillLevel();">Hard<br>
</td>
```

Additionally, I have one other thing. Why are you using `prompt()` for showing the user their selection? Use `alert()` instead.

Comment: You can attach a click event to a form.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement

Comment: I'm aware that you can attach an `onclick` handler to a form but for the purposes of form "submission" it's absolutely not ideal. The handler would be listening for any click within the visible area of the `<form></form>` element, not just the radio buttons.